# Why does ‘tmux’ create new windows as login shells by default?

Tags: shell, tmux

When you start a new session in [`tmux`](https://superuser.com/tags/tmux/info) or create a new window inside a running session, its default behavior is to run a shell (ex.: `bash`) as a "login shell".

I understand that a login shell is intended to execute a routine of configurations and procedures that are of interest *just when you are logging in a system*. But in the majority of the cases (with the exception that you can use `tmux` *as* a login shell) it’s not the true intent of the user to do this when they just wants to open a new window.

So what is the rationale for making this the default behavior of `tmux`?

---

The only thing the documentation says about the matter:

> ```
> default-command  shell-command
> ```

```
        Set the command used for new windows (if not specified when the
        window is created) to shell-command, which may be any sh(1)
        command.  The default is an empty string, which instructs tmux
        to create a login shell using the value of the default-shell
        option.
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Interactive non-login shell usually never outlive your top level login shell, therefore they can expect any facilities started by it to be available anytime, but this is not the case with tmux:

- you log in to your shell -> your login scripts are run
- you run tmux, do something, detach
- exit your top level shell -> your logout scripts are run
- tmux session is still running but any facilities started by your login shell are not available at this time
- you log in again and re attach from another login shell
- any facilities started by the new login shell may not be visible by tmux because it is still running with the old environment (even though there are commands to update the environment)

Some may think having tmux start login shells is unnecessary anyway because in most setups there are no logout scripts, and login scripts just set up some environment variables.

Furthermore if you append strings to your environment variables in your login scripts (like this: PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path) and they are run more than once in the same process hierarchy you end up with duplicates, and this is most annoying.

But still I tend to think the default makes sense.

See also this:
http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/tmux-and-login-shells-td170948.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the link! I think I can live with `exec sh` in the end... (I had not thought of that.)

Comment: Do you have any concrete examples of things that could break if tmux didn't spawn a log-in shell? I'm thinking of making that my default, but I don't want to run into hard-to-diagnose problems down the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmux attach-session
```

Will not create a new login by default, so it makes sense that

```
tmux
```

will always create a new shell by default else it wouldn't have a shell to work  with if none existed already. As such if you delete the newly created shell tmux immediately exits.

Better use tmux [resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) &/ [continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) via the tmux plugin manager
to keep your place whenever you reconnect to a shell e.g using ssh
However they also depend on tmux and it's default behavior.